# Anyway to produce Apex code out of layout?

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

This is a longshot, but...  I've produced a fairly meticulous and large layout for an object and now the business is asking me to do something that can't be done out of the box on the layout, so I am going to have to make a VF page that looks exactly the same but some functionality is different.

My question is this.  Is there anyway to generate Visualforce markup out of a page layout so that I don't have to reinvent the wheel and waste all this time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This package has been out on AppExchange for a number of years:

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wZkUEAU

I've not used it, but reviews are positive, and I've always kept it in the back of my mind for a rainy day.

Comment: This has literally saved me hours!!!

Comment: I'd say you're welcome, but someone else did all the work. And thank goodness for them. :-)

Comment: Thanks Peter., This is definitely helpful and i am going to try this app.